# own csv reader to string array out of memory

Tags: android, csv, arrays

because i am only reading a very simple csv, where only strings are comma separated and should be converted to a String[].

I thought this was so easy a external jar would be a bit to much and i could handle this very easy. But what happens is that the first item get added until the memory is full and crash!

public List readWinkels(Activity a){
        List winkelList = new ArrayList();

```
        try{
            InputStream winkelcsv =  a.getResources().getAssets().open("winkels.csv");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(winkelcsv, "UTF-8"));
            String s  = br.readLine();
            while (s != null){
                winkelList.add(s);
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }

            br.close();
            for(int i =0;i<winkelList.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(winkelList.get(i));
                }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return winkelList;
```

here is my code.... i dont get why it doesnt work, can anyone help? A readline reads the line and then the reading points jumps to the next line (i think) so why is the first line added a zillion times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the standard idiom for using a `while` loop to iterate over lines of a file, applied to your code:

```
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
    winkelList.add(s);
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}
```

You need to call `readLine()` at every iteration through the loop. The original code is nothing but an infinite loop, since `s` is only read once. Assuming `s` is not `null`, the loop condition is never false, so the list grows without bound until all available memory is used.